# Slowly Changing Dimension: Expiration field from the Source table

Tags: azure, oracle-adf, scd

I need to implement slowly changing dimension (SCD) type 2 logic in Azure Data Factory. The row expiration logic is based on a field in the source table called '**last_modified_date**' For a new record, this value should be the '**start_date**', and for a changed record, it should be the '**end_date**'.

How to achieve this in ADF?

I followed [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/OwYipQmhGMk?si=8VYIZx3sse8xy1WZ) but it would not work if the expiry date is coming from the source but works fine with the current_date as start date.

Answer (score 0):

- In order to update the `end_date` column with `last_updated_value` of source csv, you can change the broadcast settings of exist transformation as shown in below image.

[image]

- This setting will make sure that data from csv and sql table are displayed as output of exist transformation.
- Then take the derived column transformation and set the value for `isactive` as 0 and `end_date` as `last_modified_date`

[image]

This way, you can add the value of `last_modified_date` in the enddate column.